# GTA - How can I add a prop to a character?

Tags: modeling, rigging, objects, external-applications

I'm just texturing and adding a helmet on to a skin of [GTA San Andreas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Theft_Auto:_San_Andreas). In Blender everything looks fine and my problem actually occurs in game. So I basically I just <kbd>Shift</kbd> +<kbd>LMB</kbd> both objects (helmet and the skin) and merged them:

[image]

But for whatever reason my helmet is located far away from the character and I have no idea what I did wrong. Should work right?

[image: https://imgur.com/a/Ik2Fmf4]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be succinct, unique and identifying, and summarize what the issue is so that users can at a glance broadly understand what your post is about before opening it. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid any emojis salutations or extraneous text not essential to the question. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and will weight heavily on their decision to open your question, which will directly affect the number of answers you might get.

Comment: Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIFs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)